# Layer definition Limit Sliverlight API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using ESRI Sliverlight API 3.1 using layer definition in dynamic service layer, when I create a definition ID in ('1','2','3'......'1000001') . This definition is not getting applied, when I pass big string in REST unable to perform the query. But I need to set a filter based on ID, but I cannot number of ids. How to resolve the issue?

```
                LayerDefinition def = new LayerDefinition();
                def.LayerID = layerId;
                def.Definition = "ID" + " in " + idString;
                dynamicServiceLayer.LayerDefinitions.Add(def);
```

Comment: For your idString, are you passing in your id numbers in quotes? Is it "ID in ('1','2','3',..." or "ID in (1,2,3,..."?

Comment: idString = ID in ('1', '2','3'.....'1000001')

Comment: Try passing the numbers in without quotes. ObjectIds are numeric, and your database server may be reading those as strings.

Comment: These are not object ID's..variable name I have given in sample ID..